# Lombardi Java API

Tags: java

Can anyone give me some links for JAVA API for Lombardi BPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the pure java API is deprecated and all that is left to use is the web API. It has worked for me even though it is a bit under documented. You can get more info from the [Developer Guide](https://support.lombardi.com/docs/archive/Teamworks6/Teamworks6.2/Teamworks-6.2-Developers_Guide.pdf).